# select matching data from mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables t1 and t2,
table t1 contains data like be

```
count routingid  addreesid
1        1125      804
3        1125      804
4        304       5
```

and table t2 contains data like below

```
count routingid  addreesid
5        1125      804
7        1125      804
2        303        4
```

I am executing below query to get matching data from t1 only

```
select t1.* from t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.routingid=t2.routingid and t1.addreesid=t2.addreesid
```

this query returns below data

```
count routingid  addreesid
5        1125      804
7        1125      804
5        1125      804
7        1125      804
```

Comment: It's proper join behavior. There are 2 matching tuples in t2 for each tuple in t1

Comment: ok.. But I don't want duplicate records. I want 2 rows from table t1 that are matching with t2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not surprising since you have duplicates.

```
5        1125      804
```

The above row in t2 can be joined to both the following rows.

```
5        1125      804
7        1125      804
```

Similarly

```
3        1125      804
```

Can also be joined to the same rows. So four rows is the expected result here and that's what you have got.

It's not clear why you even have two tables with the same columns and apparently the same data. You really ought to consider normalizing them.

A temporary solution that sweeps the problem under the carpet is to use distinct

```
select distinct t1.* from t1 
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.routingid=t2.routingid
  and t1.addreesid=t2.addreesid
```

Comment: Thanks .. can you please help me to get 2 matching records from table t1 only.